# Table constellation for favoriting a joke

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm developing a tiny web-App in my free time and now I want to have jokes that can be favorited by the user.

My tables are:

```
----------------
| jokes        |
----------------
| id
| author_id
| content

----------------
| favorites    |
----------------
| id
| joke_id
| user_id
```

(Of course there are more tables like the users table, but aren't necessary for that)

I don't know how to set up the relationships in the models now.
My goal is to retrieve all jokes that were favorited by the logged in user, like:

```
$favorites = Joke::wherePivot('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

So that I  can access the properties like with the jokes:

```
$jokes = Joke::all();
```

In Blade template engine

```
@foreach($jokes as $joke)
  {{ $joke->content }}
@enndforeach
```

Any best practices?  I'm running Laravel Framework version 4.2.17.

Comment: i don't know your platform, but i have tables like this. First i get `joke_id`s which has linked to logged in `user_id` from `favorites` table. Then i get `favorite` details, with `joke_id` i have got, from `jokes` table

Comment: What is your question?  Looking for suggestions and "best practices" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the favorites table as followed:

joke_id | user_id

Put the primary key on both fields. 
If you want to make it "perfect" put a separate foreign key on the individual fields pointing to respectively the joke and user tables.

Each time the logged in user favorites a joke, store the joke_id and the user_id.

**Retrieval**

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jokes j 
INNER JOIN favorites f ON j.id=f.joke_id
WHERE f.user_id= $userId
```

**Using Laravel Query Builder:**

```
DB::table('jokes')
            ->join('favorites', 'jokes.id', '=', 'favorites.joke_id')
            ->where('favorites.user_id', '=', $userId)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for your reply!
But how would you setup the relationships in the models?

Comment: Are you using the "default" Eloquent models shipped with Laravel?

Comment: Yes, I do, like:
> function favorites() {
> return $this->hasMany('Favorit', 'favorites', 'user_id', 'joke_id');
> }

Comment: I am not a very frequent Laravel user, but if I do use it I generally take the Query Builder approach, since I find it more flexible and easier to use to be honest. I edited my answer for you to use the Query Builder.
If you want to do it through ORM you can find it here: [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), specifically search for the "Has Many Through" relation.

Answer (score 0):

U can get with mysql query
assume that userid =u0001

```
SELECT j.id,j.author_id,j.Content,f.user_id
FROM jokes j 
JOIN favorites f 
ON j.id=f.jokeid
WHERE f.user_id='u0001'
```